# How to run a MySQL query through Node Js Module File

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to make a separate file consisting of some functions which will return the result of my MySQL queries.
Here is what I have done so far, I have a file called 
**db_connection.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "mypassword",
  database: "dbname"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log("Couldn't connect to the Database");
  console.log("Connected to the database");
});


exports.result = (myQuery) => {
  con.query(myQuery, function (err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    return res;
  })
}
```

My file from where I am calling contains the following:

```
const db = require('../db_connection');

console.log(db.result("SELECT * FROM products"));
```

I can see in the console that the connection is established but instead of returning the array of `products` it returns `undefined`

Comment: Rather than use this way, you should go for Knex or sequelize means ORM for DB query handling

Comment: I took a quick look at Knex, but still, the problem remains the same. I will have to require it in multiple files. I just want to avoid repeating myself.